# How to use formatted html with dynamically generated html tags

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am creating a component in angular 2. Constructor of this component calls a service method getData. getData returns news items with NewsHeader and NewsBody. Based on returned items, dynamic html is generated for carousel control. News body can be a html formatted text e.g. `&lt;strong&gt;News Body&lt;/strong&gt;`

I want news body to be displayed as html formated text i.e. as **News Body** instead of `&lt;strong&gt;News Body&lt;/strong&gt;`

I have tried following code

```
constructor(private _newsService: NewsService) {
    this._newsService.getData(this.appId).subscribe(news => {
        for(let i = 0; i < news.length; i=i+2) {
            if(i==0) {
                this.slideclass = "item active";
            } else {
                this.slideclass = "item";
            }
            this.htmlText = this.htmlText + `
              <div class="` + this.slideclass + `"  style="margin-left: -50px;">`;
            for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if(news[i + j] !== undefined) {
                    this.div = "";

                    this.htmlText = this.htmlText + `
                      <ul class="thumbnails carousel-ul" style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li class="col-sm-6">
                          <div class="fff">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h4 style="color:#702082">` + news[i + j].newsHeader + `</h4>
                                  <p><div [innerHTML]=` + news[i + j].newsBody + `></div></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>`
                }
            }
            this.htm lText = this.htmlText + `</div>`;

        }
    });
}
```

When i checked developers tool, output is getting rendered as

```
<div [innerhtml]="<strong>News" body&lt;="" strong&gt;=""></div>
```

**Edit 1**
I am setting the innetHTML as

```
<div class="carousel-inner" [innerHtml]="htmlText | safeHtml">
```

where safeHtml is a pipe

```
transform(value:string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're trying to "inject" your `html` this way rather than using something like [*ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor)?

Comment: I am using this html to generate multi slide bootstrap carousel. Since i have to set conditional css class (item active) for first two slides of carousel, i thought of using this approach.

Comment: how are you passing your `this.textHtml` to the `[innerHTML]` directive btw? can you show that template?

Comment: I modified my question to add more details.